# How do I prevent my text field from becoming the first responder when selecting a choice in an alert?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, first-responder

I am trying to do validation on the entry in a text field in textFieldShouldEndEditing, I check to see if the value is non numeric or out of bounds, then call a function that displays an alert. After the alert is displayed, I set the value to a default and then call other functions to perform calculations.

Regardless of what action I choose to dismiss the alert, editing of the text field is triggered. This is what I want for the first option ("Try Again"), but for the option "Set to Default" I just want to alert to go away and not begin editing of the text field, as the default value was already assigned. I do not understand how alerts interact with first responder status or why the text field is given first responder status again. Relevant code:

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    var InvalidFlagText: String = ""
    let WindIntBool = isStringAnInt(string: textField.text!)
    if WindIntBool { //if entered wt is numeric, check to see if out of bounds of data loaded in table
        if WindInt < LowestWind || WindInt > HighestWind { //value is out of bounds of data, set to default
                txtWind.text = "0"
    //                display alert
                InvalidFlagText = "OutofBounds"
                DisplayAlert(InvalidFlag: InvalidFlagText)
        }
   } else { // if not numeric, set to default value
            txtWind.text = "0"

            //                display alert
            InvalidFlagText = "Nonnumeric"
            DisplayAlert(InvalidFlag: InvalidFlagText)

   }
CalculateResults()
    return true
}


 func DisplayAlert (InvalidFlag: String) {
    var messageText: String = ""
    if InvalidFlag == "Nonnumeric" {
        messageText = "Please enter a numeric value."
    } else if InvalidFlag == "OutofBounds" {
        messageText = "Entered value is outside of the valid numeric range. Please enter a valid numeric value"
    }

       let alert = UIAlertController(title: "That is an invalid entry.", message: "\(messageText)", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Set to Default", style: .default, handler: { action in

    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: A little heads up - Naming convention not cool.

Answer (score 1):

try resign all responders on your alert

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Set to Default", style: .default, handler: { action in
      //// set your text value before ////
      self.view.endEditing(true)
}))
```

Right or better way:

```
func DisplayAlert (InvalidFlag: String) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    var messageText: String = ""
    if InvalidFlag == "Nonnumeric" {
        messageText = "Please enter a numeric value."
    } else if InvalidFlag == "OutofBounds" {
        messageText = "Entered value is outside of the valid numeric range. Please enter a valid numeric value"
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "That is an invalid entry.", message: "\(messageText)", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
         self.txtWind.becomeFirstResponder()
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Set to Default", style: .default, handler: { action in
         /// set default value ////
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I am not a cent percent sure, but this might lead to - Alert dismissed - Keyboard dismissed. The ideal way would be to dismiss the keyboard before the alert is displayed. But again, I might be wrong.

Comment: I had tried this previously; this send me into a loop where it keeps displaying the alert unfortunately.

Comment: yes... you have to set your text value to default before. @Nitish I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what CalculateResults() method does and I assumed the isStringAnInt method as well. Below is the code for the functionality you are expecting.

```
import UIKit

let kDEFAULT_WIND = "0"

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var txtWind: UITextField!
let HighestWind = 200
let LowestWind = 100
var WindInt = -1
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    txtWind.delegate = self
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)

    return true
}
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField.text == kDEFAULT_WIND{
        return true
    }
    var InvalidFlagText: String = ""
    let WindIntBool = isStringAnInt(s: textField.text!)
    if WindIntBool { //if entered wt is numeric, check to see if out of bounds of data loaded in table
        if WindInt < LowestWind || WindInt > HighestWind { //value is out of bounds of data, set to default
            InvalidFlagText = "OutofBounds"
            DisplayAlert(InvalidFlag: InvalidFlagText)
        }
    } else { // if not numeric, set to default value
        InvalidFlagText = "Nonnumeric"
        DisplayAlert(InvalidFlag: InvalidFlagText)

    }
//        CalculateResults()
    return true
}

func isStringAnInt(s : String) -> Bool{
    if let val = Int(s){
        WindInt = val
        return true
    }
    return false
}
func DisplayAlert (InvalidFlag: String) {
    var messageText: String = ""
    if InvalidFlag == "Nonnumeric" {
        messageText = "Please enter a numeric value."
    } else if InvalidFlag == "OutofBounds" {
        messageText = "Entered value is outside of the valid numeric range. Please enter a valid numeric value"
    }
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "That is an invalid entry.", message: "\(messageText)", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now(), execute: {
            self.txtWind.text = kDEFAULT_WIND
            self.txtWind.becomeFirstResponder()
        })
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Set to Default", style: .default, handler: { action in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now(), execute: {
            self.txtWind.text = kDEFAULT_WIND
            self.txtWind.resignFirstResponder()
        })
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}

}
```

Comment: This worked, you and GIJOW are both correct. This issue was that I was setting the default value prior to calling DisplayAlert and relying on that, instead of setting it after a action was clicked. Thank you both.